# insert rollback after caught exception postgres

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a postgres function called from php.  The first line of the function inserts something in a table returning the key into a local.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uploadConfirm( bname text, ul text, pt text,  
                                          shp text, vzn integer, 
                                          gpsLoc double precision[], meta text ) RETURNS void   AS $uC$
DECLARE
        file Files%ROWTYPE;
        shape text[];
        locat_id integer;
        crl_id integer;
        uid integer DEFAULT(null);
        iid integer;
        make text;
        model text;
BEGIN
        insert into interact(webRequest) values(bname) RETURNING interact_id into iid;
        shape := regexp_split_to_array( shp, E'x' );  -- get info for single file
        --meta := encode( meta , 'base64' );
        RAISE NOTICE 'uploadConfirm: % : % : % : % : % : % : %' , bname, ul, pt, shp , vzn, gpsLoc , meta ;
        locat_id := getLocationId( gpsLoc[1],gpsLoc[2],gpsLoc[3] );
        --RAISE 'meta: %d' , meta;
        make := (regexp_matches( meta , $$Make\s+=\s+'([^']+)'$$ ))[1];
        model := (regexp_matches( meta , $$Model\s+=\s+'([^']+)'$$ ))[1];
        --RAISE  '>> shape , loc_id, make, model: % : % : % : % ' , shape, loc_id, make, model  ;
        crl_id := getCurlId( '' , ul, pt, vzn );
        select * into  file from Files  where Files.basename = bname;
        IF NOT FOUND THEN
               insert into Files 
               ( basename , curl_id  ) VALUES 
               ( bname , crl_id ) returning * into file;
           ELSE 
               update Files set ( curl_id  ) = 
                                ( crl_id  )
                                where basename = bname;
               update interact set ( uid ) = ( file.uid ) where interact_id = iid;
        END IF;          
        INSERT INTO Metadata VALUES ( meta , make , model , cast(shape[1] as integer), cast( shape[2] as integer) , file.file_id, locat_id );
     EXCEPTION 
         WHEN not_null_violation THEN
              perform reportError( 'File(bname='|| bname || ' no location data:' || SQLERRM, iid );
     END;
$uC$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This function has an exception clause which calls an error reporting function shown below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reportError( msgX text, iidX integer default(null) ) returns void as $re$
       DECLARE
       BEGIN
        if iidX is null then
            SELECT currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('interact', 'interact_id')) into iidX;
        END IF;
        insert into err (msg,iid) values ( msgX,iidX );
       END;
$re$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

which calls another function **reportError** which places info (including a filename, **bname,** and the key, **iid**, shown above)  about the exception in a table.

When I look, although the error information is in the table as it should be.  The entry with corresponding  key is missing from the **interact** table.  Insertion into interact can only fail when bname is null; however, the value of bname (!=NULL) is present in the error message, so the failure I am catching must be later in the code as expected.

Seems to me the insertion into **interact** shouldn't be rolled back but it, apparently, is.

I don't understand why this entry is not in the **interact** table.  Can someone explain why & help me figure out how to get it there.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to show the full function, or at least the relevant block, as well as the definition of `reportError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

postgres docs say this exaclty what is supposed to happen

```
When an error is caught by an EXCEPTION clause, the local variables 
of the PL/pgSQL function remain as they were when the error occurred, but 
all changes to persistent database state within the block are rolled back.
```

I should say RTM, to myself.

I can redo the insert, which I want in the exception handler.